# How to predict cupy array using a trained model?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, predict, cupy

I want to make prediction using a trained model, but it seems the model cannot take cupy data as input. The snippets of my codes are listed below:

```
import cupy as cp
model_evaluator = my_model()
model_evaluator.build_model()
model_evaluator.model.load_weights(trained_model)

model_evaluator.model.predict(my_cupy_data) # throws error here
model_evaluator.model.predict(cp.asnumpy(my_cupy_data)) # works fine
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

ENV: conda + python 3.6 + tensorflow 2.1.0

Error: InvalidArgumentError
TypeError: len() of unsized object

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the CuPy array into a TensorFlow tensor.

```
tensor = tf.experimental.dlpack.from_dlpack(cupy_array.toDlpack())
```